# Modify how property names are serialized with NewtonSoft.Json

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I'm using `NewtonSoft.Json` in my application to serialize many types of objects into strings and send them to third-party services. Now, some of these services have restriction on Json format, for example they do not support dots in JSON property names:

```
{
   "PropertyOne":{
      "SubProperty.One":"SubValue.One" <- invalid!
   },
   "Property.Two":"ValueTwo"  <- invalid!
}
```

How can I modify the way `NewtonSoft.Json` serializes objects so that it replaces all dots in property names with, say, underscores:

```
{
   "PropertyOne":{
      "SubProperty_One":"SubValue.One"
   },
   "Property_Two":"ValueTwo"
}
```

*Note*: I cannot achieve this with `DataAnnotations` attributes, as some of the objects I serialize are in third-party libraries, and I cannot modify them.

Comment: Would it be an option to map third-party type to your own type and the apply `JsonPropertyAttribute` not to write custom `JsonConverter`?

Comment: Do you know how 3rd party objects are attributed? Do they have `JsonProperty` applied?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this pretty easily with a custom ContractResolver:

```
class ReplaceDotsWithUnderscoresResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        JsonProperty prop = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);
        prop.PropertyName = prop.PropertyName.Replace('.', '_');
        return prop;
    }
}
```

Use it like this:

```
JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    ContractResolver = new ReplaceDotsWithUnderscoresResolver(),
    Formatting = Formatting.Indented
};

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(your_object, settings);
```

Working demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/hQOJdh

Comment: This does work for the example I provided but fails to work for cases like custom implementation of `ISerializable`, `Dictionary` properties, etc. Is there nay way in Json.NET to take care of *all* property names regardless of the mechanism that was used to serialize them? (demo showing the problem: https://dotnetfiddle.net/XwIPLH )

Answer (score 0):

You could use AutoMapper and map third-party type to you own type. Then you will be able to apply [JsonPropertyAttribute](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/serializationattributes.htm#JsonPropertyAttribute) to properties where you need custom names.

Another approach could be to replace resulting JSON with regular expression:

```
var json = @"{
    ""PropertyOne"":{
        ""SubProperty.One"":""SubValue.One""
 },
    ""Property.Two.Three"":""ValueTwo""
 }";

string result;

while (true)
{
    result = Regex.Replace(json, @"(""[^.]+)(\.)(.+"":)", "$1_$3", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    if (json == result)
    {
        break;
    }
    json = result;
}

Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Which will output result in a way you want:

```
{
    "PropertyOne":{
        "SubProperty_One":"SubValue.One"
},
    "Property_Two_Three":"ValueTwo"
}
```

Comment: I explicitly stated in my question that I cannot modify my model in any way, as it is part of a third-party library

Comment: Sorry, missed that bit.

Comment: @AndriiLitvinov I still think your answer has value, maybe not to OP, but to future visitors. Would probably be better with an example though :)

Comment: @Default, I have just googled a bit and found a bunch of similar answers. Currently I am thinking that the way to go is custom json converter. So I will either update my answer or remove it.

Comment: Automapper can be a solution for simple flat POCO objects, but it won't help if the object I want to serialize contains dozens of proprties that are themseves very compex types. It would be an enormous job to copy the whole object structure of uncertain depth, and clearly an overkill for the task I want to perform.

Comment: Custom type converter is even bigger overkill.

Comment: @Nazz, would it be an option to identify places like `SubProperty.One` in JSON and replace with `SubProperty_One` after JSON is generated?

Comment: @AndriiLitvinov, I'm looking for a generic solution that does exactly what I wrote in the question: replaces all dots in all property names.

Comment: @Nazz, sure I got it. Good luck. Please post your solution here when you find it.

Comment: @Nazz, I have updated my answer, It will do what you want. Was fun to fine  a way. Looking forward to see how else it can be done. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways to achieve what you want is intercepting the serialization/deserialization process early, by doing some overrides the JsonReader and JsonWriter.

```
public class CustomSerializer : JsonConverter
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (value == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("value");

        var properties = value.GetType().GetProperties();
        writer.WriteStartObject();
        foreach (var property in properties)
        {
            string propertyName = property.Name.Replace('.', '_');
            // just write new property name and value
            writer.WritePropertyName(propertyName);
            writer.WriteValue(property.GetValue(value, new object[] { }));

        }

        writer.WriteEndObject();
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JObject jsonObject = JObject.Load(reader);
        List<JProperty> properties = jsonObject.Properties().ToList();

        object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(objectType);

        PropertyInfo[] objectProperties = objectType.GetProperties();
        foreach (var objectProperty in objectProperties)
        {
            JProperty jsonProperty = properties.SingleOrDefault(prop => prop.Name == objectProperty.Name.Replace('_', '.'));
            if (jsonProperty != null)
            {
                objectProperty.SetValue(instance, jsonProperty.Value.ToString(), new object[] { });
            }
        }

        return instance;
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return true; // your logic here
    }
}
```

and usage:

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(your_object, new CustomSerializer());
```